# How do I add data to a table in SQLite Studio? (error occuring)

Tags: mysql, sqlite, sqlitestudio

I am using SQLite Studio version 3.0.7 (which I assume is the latest version) to create a table. I have added 2 columns (name and age), and now I wish to add data into the table (eg. John age 30, Adam age 50).

However, it's not actually letting me add any data into the table. The 'Populate table' icon is grey and won't let me click on it. I have attached a screenshot to show you what I mean. What could be the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a new table you are creating. After you decided about all columns you want to have in it you need to commit it using green button - on the left from "populate". Then you will be able to populate the table and do other things with it.

Comment: Thanks, works now. Can't believe I didn't figure that out myself, lol!